# Add transform speed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, transform, transition

I would like to add some speed in a transformation that I made with Javascript, but I don't exactly know how..

My Javascript code is

```
$('#cell1').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1 1) translate(200, 10)');
```

And my this class is inside my html code. 
How should I add some speed?

I tried this

```
$(this).attr('transition-duration', '3s');
```

but it doesn't quite work..

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 problems in your code:

1. use `$.css()` instead of `$.attr()`
2. separate CSS `scale` value with a comma
3. add units for translation

This will work:

```
$(this).css('transform', 'scale(1, 1) translate(200px, 10px)');
$(this).css('transition-duration', '3s');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/781wuxym/

Comment: Thank you! I just want to ask, if I put pixels to translate, would this also work responsively? (Would it transform the same amount when I transform it in another screen size?)

Comment: This is an entirely different question and doesn't have a short answer. You might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length carefully to choose the right length unit for your specification. For responsive behaviour I usually go with `rem` and adjust the font size on the `html` element for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of `.attr()`.

Also, you need to ensure that you are using your css functions correctly. For example, you need to make sure `translate` uses `px` for the coordinates and that `scale` is comma separated (if h & w are the same you can just specify 1 unit).

See working example below:

```js
$('#cell1').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css({
     "transition-duration": "3s", 
     "transform": "scale(1) translate(200px, 10px)"
  });
});
```

```css
#cell1 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cell1"></div>
```